# How to setup PYTHONPATH env in VScode properly

Tags: python-2.7, visual-studio-code, pythonpath

The project structure is like

```
- a.py
- unittest
   - test_a.py
```

**A.py**

```
class A():
    def function_a(self):
        return 'function_a'
```

**test_a.py**

```
from a import A

class TestA():
    def test_a(self):
        assert A().function_a() == 'function_a'
```

When I use terminal and `set PATHONPATH=//<my-project-folder>`, it can be detected and tested via `pytest`. However, when I tried to debug it in VScode, it kept throwing out `No module named a`.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file

I've tried this way and put a `.env` inside my project folder.

**.env**

```
PYTHONPATH=C:\\Repos\\test-project
```

(I did it with and without escaping, it didn't work anyway.)

**.vscode/setting.json**

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Python27\\python.exe",
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "unittest"
    ],
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To find out what the value is of the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable use the following `test_a.py` file

```
import os

def test_PYTHONPATH():
  assert os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH') == "XX"
```

I have tested it on Windows with Python 3.6.

In my test I have set an `.env` in the workspace root folder with the content

```
PYTHONPATH=C:\Projects\test-project\
```

Running the test gave an assertion error and showed that the value of `PYTHONPATH` was the value defined by the OS.

Starting a terminal and removing `PYTHONPATH` from the global environment variables and starting VSC from this terminal with `C:\Projects\test-project\` as argument opened the project and now the test fails but shows the correct `PYTHONPATH` as defined in the `.env` file.

I get the conclusion that the OS environment variables (on Windows) override any environment variable set by VSC. If this is correct you can't extend the environment variable like it is shown in the docs

```
PYTHONPATH=${PROJ_DIR}:${PYTHONPATH}
```

This should be filed as an error in VSC or the VSC-python extension.

Anything defined in VSC should override any OS environment variable and be able to use any OS environment variable.